# Custom error page in tomcat for HTTP 501 error

Tags: tomcat8, http-error

Before anything else, I've already read all those solutions that says I put an error-page block in my application's or tomcat's conf/web.xml and add an error-code block inside with the corresponding location and those didn't work (did those for 404 errors and those worked).

What I already did inside my application's and tomcat's web.xml:

```
<error-page> <!-- this worked -->
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/pageNotFound.html</location>
</error-page>

<error-page> <!-- this did not work -->
    <error-code>501</error-code>
    <location>/pageNotFound.html</location>
</error-page>
```

I'm using Tomcat 8.5.63, and the goal is to remove the "Apache Tomcat/8.5.63" part on the response whenever a 501 error appears.

I want to remove this part:
[tomcat error response page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8qSr.png)

The way I'm testing this is that I intercept a request using a pentest tool (I'm using burp suite community) and modify a request to include a `Transfer-Encoding: cow` header (yes I know that header is invalid).

Any ideas on how to implement a custom page so that the 501 can be handled properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error pages you declare are used in two situations:

> To allow developers to customize the appearance of content returned to a Web client
> when a servlet generates an error, the deployment descriptor defines a list of error
> page descriptions. The syntax allows the configuration of resources to be returned by
> the container either when a servlet or filter **calls `sendError`** on the response for
> specific status codes, or if the servlet **generates an exception** or error that propagates
> to the container.

([Servlet 4.0 Specification](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-4.0/servlet-4_0_FINAL.pdf), section 10.9.2)

In your case the error happens much earlier during the processing of the HTTP request itself. Therefore you need to modify the server's configuration (`server.xml`) and add a custom `ErrorReportValve` (cf. [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Error_Report_Valve)). If all you want is to omit the server's version string, just add:

```xml
<Host>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" showServerInfo="false" />
    ...
</Host>
```